# pymssql issue with cutting off after 255 characters

Tags: string, max, string-length, pymssql

I have installed pymssql (using _mssql) version 1.0.2 and I noticed that when I start looking at the fields in the result set it appears to be cutting off large text fields at 255 characters max.  I scoured the internet for any mention of this but found nothing - I have no idea why it is cutting the string off at this point, but the database is definitely returning a longer string than that.  Any help is appreciated - could it just be as easy as a version upgrade, or is this something I need to work around?

Thanks!

As per your request, I am inserting an obscured code snippet detailing what I am talking about - this is a Python script on an Ubuntu system:

```
import sys
import shutil
import fileinput
import os
import _mssql

myServer = 'hostIP'
myUID = 'userID'
myPW = 'mypass'
myDB = 'theDBName'
theID  = 'ABC123'

myConn = _mssql.connect(server=myServer, user=myUID, password=myPW, database=myDB)
myConn.execute_query("SELECT method FROM myTable WHERE id = '" + theID + "'")

for myRow in myConn:
  method = myRow["method"]
  len(method) # This prints out 255
  len(myRow["method")) # This prints out 255

myConn.close()
```

FYI : the string returned from the database is over 900 characters in length, but I only see the first 255 of it.

Comment: Please add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/limitations.php) with pymssql (or rather, the underlying protocol).

> varchar and nvarchar data is limited to 255 characters, and longer strings are silently trimmed.
>   This is known limitation of TDS protocol. A workaround is to CAST or CONVERT that row or expression to text data type, which is capable of returning 4000 characters.

Comment: This was the issue - I converted it to datatype TEXT in the query and it works!  Thank you SO much!